# How to disable the sending of Magento's default Success Email Template upon newsletter sign-up

Tags: email, email-templates

Magento CE 1.9.0.1

We recently signed up for an email and list management service that taps into Magento and allows us to manage all transactional and newsletter emails through their application. This is a very convenient service and we would like to disable some of our outgoing Magento emails and just their service handle it. The only problem is that they are new to Magento and do not currently have an option to disable the default emails that Magento sends out which would result in customers getting two sets of emails - specifically, I need to disable the Newsletter Subscription Success email, Order Update email and New Account Signup email.

Does anyone know of a way to do this programmatically?

I found this thread on SE which addresses the Newsletter Subscription email https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844023/magento-store-dont-send-newsletter-success-email

There also seem to be an extension which has mixed reviews because it doesn't address custom email templates and has a few bugs: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-email-notifications.html

Comment: See [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143029/how-to-disable-sending-of-newsletter-email-in-magento2/143030#143030) for a Magento2 solution.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/aurmil/magento-disable-newsletter-notifications) for a Magento 1 extension that adds 2 new options to the Newsletter Subscriber Options to disable this.

Answer (score 8):

don't need to install extension and make load on site.
go to
\app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html
delete full page content .
and from now you don't get any mail on news later subscription.

Comment: If you are running a good OS, you'll need forward slashes `rm "app/locale/en_US/template/email/newsletter_subscr_success.html"`

Answer (score 6):

I just figured out a neat little hack to disable the subscription confirmation email without any class rewrites or code-level modification.  It's definitely kind of a hack though.

You can open up your console and manually change the value of the `<select>` to zero:

[image]

There's a place within the sendConfirmationSuccessEmail method where it checks that that value is truthy:

[image]

So if it's zero, the email won't be sent out.

What sucks about this approach is that if you ever come back to the newsletter settings for any reason and save something else, you will almost certainly inadvertently reset that value back to the default non-zero value, which makes this hack probably not a good idea for anyone to use.

But still thought it would be interesting to post here for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to override the classes that are currently sending out these emails.

For the newsletter, it is Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail().

For the new account, it is Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountEmail().

For the order update, you can turn this off in the system configuration. Look in system -> configuration -> sales emails -> order comments: set 'enabled' to false.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Mailchimp integration](https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/magento) with Magento that exists for a long time and is very stable. They override the correct models and templates to accomplish this task, so now I'm wondering how your service is accomplishing that, if they don't use the proper hooks. It's something you need to figure out before overriding or disabling things that they may need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free extension for [disabling email notifications](https://github.com/MageryThemes/magento-disable-emails) in Magento 1