# How to disable sending of Newsletter email in Magento2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I ran across an [old thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59034/how-to-disable-the-sending-of-magentos-default-success-email-template-upon-news) on how to disable sending of newsletter emails, but it was for Magento 1.9.

How can we disable sending of newsletter emails in Magento2?

Answer (score 8):

We can do this in Magento2 using [Plugins (Interceptors)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#defining-a-plugin)

In *di.xml* of a custom plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="my-subscriber" type="MyNamespace\MyModule\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" sortOrder="1" disabled="1" />
</type>
```

Then your Interceptor class which wraps the underlying `Subscriber` instance and turns all sending methods into no-ops

```
namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Newsletter\Model;

use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber as MageSubscriber;

/**
 * Don't send any newsletter-related emails.
 * These will all go out through our marketing platform.
 */
class Subscriber
{
    public function aroundSendConfirmationRequestEmail(MageSubscriber $oSubject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $oSubject;
    }
    public function aroundSendConfirmationSuccessEmail(MageSubscriber $oSubject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $oSubject;
    }
    public function aroundSendUnsubscriptionEmail(MageSubscriber $oSubject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $oSubject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, short and clean

Comment: But this is also stopping mailchimp emails